# Is it possible to pass a scalar value to a Pandas UDF Function along with Pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` function on two columns of pyspark dataframe.

while passing `x0` parameter as array to the Pandas UDF function, i am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [0.9  0.5  2.5  5.   0.33] of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

This is the function i am trying to minimize

```
def eb_func(theta, n, e):
    """
    # Function to be Minimized

    :param theta: float
    :param n: Pandas.Series
    :param e: Pandas.Series
    :return: float

    """
    print("Entering EB_Func")
    res = res = np.prod(theta[4] * neg_bin(n, e, theta[0], theta[1]) + (1 - theta[4]) * neg_bin(n, e, theta[2], theta[3]))
    return res
```

This is my neg_bin function:

```
@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def neg_bin(n, e, alpha, beta):
    """

    :param n:
    :param e:
    :param alpha:
    :param beta:
    :return:
    """
    res_expo = gammaln(alpha + n) - gammaln(n + 1) - gammaln(alpha)
    res = np.exp(res_expo)
    res = res / (1 + beta / (e + 0.01)) ** n
    res = res / (1 + e / beta) ** alpha
    return res
```

These are my parameters:

```
x0 = np.array([0.9, 0.5, 2.5, 5, 0.33])
bounds = ([0.000001, 200], [0.000001, 200], [0.000001, 200], [0.000001, 200], [0.000001, 1])
```

This is where i am trying to call the `scipy.optimize.minimize` Function.

```
# Define a function to call minimize function
def RunMinimize(data):
    Result = minimize(eb_func, x0, args=(data.Adolescent_a, data.Adolescent_e), method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds, options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 1000, 'eps': np.repeat(1e-4, 5)})
    return Result.x


RunMinimize(df_adol)
```

I am new to PySpark, i can do this in Pandas but now i have a huge dataset and Pandas is taking a lot of time to process that.

Following is the expected Output Format:
This is what i get as output in Pandas

```
[1.00000000e-06, 1.46304225e+00, 1.00000000e-06, 6.39066185e+00, 1.00000000e-06])
```

I am having trouble passing theta values to the neg_bin function. Because neg_bin function only expects pandas.Series as input. I am looking for a workaround to send theta values as scalar along with pandas.Series as input to the neg_bin function, if possible.

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to follow your example, but unfortunately not all functions are defined and no import statements are included. Hence, I provide a simpler example below (convert temperatures to/from C and F).

The idea is to wrap the pandas UDF in another function that takes the necessary scalar arguments. The example runs in pyspark 3.2+ and some adaptation may be needed for earlier versions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

df = [[1. , 1.1], [2., 2.1]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema = ['x', 'y'])

def temp_to_temp(from_temp: str, to_temp: str) -> pd.Series:
    @F.pandas_udf(T.DoubleType())
    def temp_to_temp_inner(value: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
        if to_temp == 'C':
            if from_temp == 'F':
                return (value - 32)*5./9
            else:
                return value
        elif to_temp == 'F':
            if from_temp == 'C':
                return value*9./5 + 32
            else:
                return value
    return temp_to_temp_inner

res = df.select(temp_to_temp('C', 'F')(F.col('x')).alias('temp (F)'))

res.show()
# |temp (F)|
# +--------+
# |    33.8|
# |    35.6|
# +--------+
```

where `spark` is the spark session.